# Two Grub Entries Load Same Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

I have a dual-boot system with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as the operating systems. My Grub loading list contains two Windows entries. They both work and appear to load the same system (as far as I can tell).

First entry:

```
    Windows /dev/sda2
    Boot Sequence

    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  2A962FC2962F8D7F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2A962FC2962F8D7F
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
```

Seconds entry:

```
    Windows /dev/sdb1    
    Boot Sequence
    
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  0CF421D4F421C136
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0CF421D4F421C136
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
```

The disk configuration is as follows:

```
sudo lsblk
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.8G  0 part /media/user/TI105741W0B
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part /media/System_Reserved
├─sdb2   8:18   0 199.9G  0 part /media/user/9486423786421A5E
├─sdb3   8:19   0   100G  0 part /
├─sdb4   8:20   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 631.5G  0 part /media/user/Playground
```

The identifiers for these disks:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb3: UUID="4d91ca11-55dd-4624-9d51-e1ded2485b81" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b763cf5f-03"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="TI105741W0B" UUID="2A962FC2962F8D7F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="fcf1ad70-02"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="0CF421D4F421C136" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b763cf5f-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="9486423786421A5E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b763cf5f-02"
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="Playground" UUID="1C74BF6274BF3CF8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b763cf5f-05"
```

My question is how I can figure out which entry to delete. I am trying to clean up Grub and HDD space, but do not want to mess up the working dual-boot.

P.S. In the past, I have used both the `sda` and `sdb2` disks as partitions with Windows installed on them. Hence, both might have Windows files remain on them. Perhaps Grub picks up on that somehow. However, the `sda` defintely does not have any `Program Files` or `Windows` directories left. I am using `sda` strictly as file storage now.

Comment: Your sda2 partition must have Windows boot files.  Windows uses boot flag, but Grub2's os-prober looks for NTFS partitions with Windows boot files. BIOS boot files that grub looks for: /bootmgr /Boot/BCD. If using MBR(msdos) then you are using the old BIOS boot configuration.

Comment: @oldfred, Are you saying that if I find those boot files and delete them, then the Grub entry may disappear after that on its own?

Comment: Yes, Boot-Repair typically copies those files as users do not have backups. I would backup those files and/or rename, so not the names grub is looking for. If Windows still works, then you can delete them. Best to have good backups of everything before any major system change, particularly with booting. And have available flash drives with current versions of repair tools for every installed system.